# `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected` - is there a reason why I am getting this in console?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have been going bald trying to figure out why this code won't run `handleSubmit` function. So basically, the the form takes an input, and run it in the `handleSubmit` function on form submit. The function makes a `POST` request to an api route with the `email and userId`, but unfortunately when I log these values to the console, I get a `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected` warning rather than the data. Can you spot what I missed or not doing right? Here is the code.

```
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { Dialog, Transition } from '@headlessui/react';
import Image from 'next/image';

export default function Team({ show, setShow, userId }) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState({ userId: userId, email: "" });
    const [emailMessage, setEmailMessage] = useState("...");
    const [emailSent, setEmailSent] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setEmail({ ...email, [name]: value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await fetch("/api/team-members", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ userId: email.userId, email: email.email })
            });

            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(email.userId, email.email) //This is not logging to the console
            console.log("DATA", data); //This is not logging to the console
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
            setEmailMessage("An error occurred while sending the invite.");
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div >
                {emailSent ? (
                    <>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => setShow(false)}
                        >
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <label htmlFor="email">
                            Member's email
                        </label>
                        <p>Please enter one or more emails separated by commas ','</p>
                        <input
                            id="email"
                            name="email"
                            type="email"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            autoComplete="email"
                            value={email.email}
                            required
                            placeholder="email@example.com"
                        />
                        <button type="submit" onClick={() => setEmailSent(true)}>
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </form>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the button you set email sent which removes the form from the DOM.

This seems to happen before the form’s submit event handler fires.

The browser tries to submit the form but it isn’t there any more.

Don’t use two event handlers for this. Do **all** the work in the submit event handler. Don’t set email sent until after you call preventDefault.

Comment: Ah, thank you sir! This seems to be the fix. Much appreciated